# Php multiple word search in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got lots of result and codes about search string. But all are search single word. I want to search multiple word and any of word match string will be display.

**Example:**

```
$string = "Apple is a big tech company!";
$search = 'Apple Logo';
```

Now I want if **"Apple Logo"** or **"Apple"** or **"Logo"** in string then it will return **True** else it will show **False**.

How I do that? I already tried lot of PHP codes. I also see `ElasticSearch` but I want something handy and easy to use.

```
if (stripos($string, $search) !== false) {
 echo "Found";
}
```

Comment: _"I also see ElasticSearch but I want something handy and easy to use."_ - Where does the text you want to search come from? Database? Text file? Hard coded? Going from regex on a string to ElasticSearch is a pretty wide jump.

Comment: Actually, I'll use this function to search inside a multidimensional array.. so my one friend suggest me to use ElasticSearch.. But I don't want to use a third party tools.

Comment: You don't show any _multidimensional array_ which may be a different answer entirely.

Comment: yeah.. I didn't add it here.. because I want a simple answer.. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888425/php-array-search-from-multidimensional-array-by-single-or-multiple-word) about this and didn't get a answer, that's why I posted this question  more simple way.

Comment: ...and where do you get that multidimensional array from? Regardless if it is in a string or if it is in an array, it comes from somewhere at some point, right?  Database? Text file? Hard coded? The answer depends on that as well since you already can search for the text if you have it in a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array of the words, replace them and check against the original:

```
if(str_ireplace(explode(' ', $search), '', $string) != $string) {
    echo "Found";
}
```

Or loop the words and check as you would with a single word:

```
foreach(explode(' ', $search) as $word) {
    if(stripos($string, $word) !== false) {
        echo "Found";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and some other fancy things.

```
$string = "Apple is a big tech company!";
$search = 'Apple Logo a';

$pattern = '/\b('.str_replace(' ', '|', preg_quote($search, '/')).')\b/i';

$arr = preg_grep($pattern, explode(' ', $string));

print_r($arr);
```

Outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Apple [2] => a )
```

Test it online

https://3v4l.org/ugbdZ

I threw the `a` in there just to show off.  As you can see it only matches `a` not `company` etc..

And as a bonus it will properly escape any Regex stuff in the search string...

Yay!

As a side note you could also use the same pattern with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) if you wish.

```
$string = "Apple is a big tech company!";
$search = 'Apple Logo a';

$pattern = '/\b('.str_replace(' ', '|', preg_quote($search, '/')).')\b/i';

$numMatch = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

print_r($numMatch);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs

```
 2
 Array (
      [0] => Array (
           [0] => Apple
           [1] => a
      )
      [1] => Array (
           [0] => Apple
           [1] => a 
      )
 )
```

Test it

https://3v4l.org/ZOlUV

The only real difference is you get a more complicated array (just use `$matches[1]`) and the count of the matches without counting said array.

Answer (score -3):

you can use this [STRPOS](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)
example:

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

this a little example.. good luck

Comment: You're on the English SO. All answers should be in English. Plus, it doesn't answer the OP's question.